# Python Image.open() does not recognize regular expression

Tags: python, regex

```
from PIL import Image
image1 = "Image_I0000_F1_Filter 1_1A_health_2014-05-20_11.05.33.483.tiff"
image2 = "*F1*.tiff"
im1 = Image.open(image1)
im2 = Image.open(image2)
```

Tried to open the same image. im1 opens with no problem, but im2 shows IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '*F1*.tiff'.

Also tried

```
image2 = r"*F1*.tiff"
im2 = Image.open(image2)
```

and

```
image2 = "*F1*.tiff"
im2 = Image.open(open(image2,'rb'))
```

neither works.

Comment: Is it supposed to?

Comment: Are you sure it exists (the picture and where the program is trying to access it)

Comment: This looks like a bug report I would file under "Not a bug."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PIL.Image.open` has no glob matching. [The documentation](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.open) advises

> You can use either a string (representing the filename) or a file object as the file argument

Notably not including glob matching.

Python uses the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module to do glob matching.

```
from PIL import Image

import glob

filenames = glob.glob("*F1*.tiff")
# gives a list of matches, in this case most likely
# # ["Image_I0000_F1_Filter 1_1A_health_2014-05-20_11.05.33.483.tiff"]
if filenames:
    filename = filenames[0]
else:
    # what do we do if there's no such file? I guess pass the empty string
    # to Image and let it deal with it
    filename = ""
    # or maybe directly...
    raise FileNotFoundError

im1 = Image.open(filename)
```